# Kivy clickable image that replaced a button

Tags: python, kivy

Looking for a way to use an image instead of a conventional button with kivy.
I try to use [background_disabled_normal](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_disabled_normal) and [background_disabled_down](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_disabled_down)
This is my button part in my .kv file:

```
Button:
    on_press: root.do_action()
    background_disabled_normal: str(False)
    Image:
        source: 'icon.png'
        y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 250
        x: self.parent.x
        size: 250, 250
        allow_stretch: True
```

But not work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> background_disabled_normal: str(False)
> ```

This should be a filepath to an image, not a string of a boolean. Also, this is the property for the background when the button's disabled property is True - are you sure you don't want `background_normal`?

There is another way to do this anyway that may suit you; the button stuff is abstracted as ButtonBehavior that may be combined with any widget.

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass
```

This ImageButton will have all the properties of an image (you can set the source) *and* all the events of a button (on_press etc).

Comment: Actually!!! I need to use `background_normal` this work perfectly =) Thank you very much!