# kivy button image display issue

Tags: image, button, kivy

I have a refresh button with a custom image. Everything looked fine, but once I upgraded to Windows 10 (I was on 8) I get this weird display issue where the image doesn't stretch to completely cover the button surface. Instead, a tiny version of the image is shown in the middle of the button.[Image shows a textbox with an oversized button for clarity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMvDk.png)

Also, here is my Kv code:

```
Button:
    id: generate_btn
    size_hint_x: 0.5
    size_hint_y: 0.5
    background_normal: 'refresh.jpg'
```

Comment: Found a workaround by following a tip for another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668317/kivy-clickable-image-that-replaced-a-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a nested Image and allow_stretch

```
Button:
    id: generate_btn
    size_hint_x: 0.5
    size_hint_y: 0.5
    Image:
        allow_stretch: True
        size: generate_btn.size
        source: 'refresh.jpg'
        pos: generate_btn.pos
```

My guess is that you have problems because you have changed screen resolution when you moved to windows 10

Comment: Tried this, but now the image doesn't stick to the button. Instead the image is displayed in the bottom left corner of the window (and yes, I checked that my indentation is right and the image is correctly nested)

Comment: Where is your button placed? in a FloatLayout? I've updated my post with a setting the pos as well

Comment: No problem ;)        .